# how to write a nginx conf with multilange to different backend

Tags: laravel, nginx

I want to deploy a multilanguage site.
like default aaa.com is English, aaa.com/jp and aaa.com/es .
I don't want to write code to implement multi-language functions，because it is someone else's code...too hard to read.
backend is a laravel app in docker.
so I create 3 container for each language.
But Nginx  is not working as I thought,
Hope someone can help to correct the configuration file.

```
server {
gzip on;
listen  443 ssl;
server_name www.aaa.com aaa.com;
root /var/www/html/public;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    
    location es/ { 
        root /var/www/html.es/public; 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
    }
    
    location / {  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        rewrite ^/es/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass es-app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I am not proficient in the configuration syntax of nginx, and I have not achieved the desired function after trying various writing methods.

Answer (score 0):

When using Nginx you have to be specially careful with the slashes, because it's very sensitive.

You cant try with `location /es/` instead of only `location es/` (Note the slash at the start)

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work. There should be many mistakes in the configuration file. hope you can help me modify it.

Comment: Since you are suggesting something to try, our response would be more appropriate as a comment on the Question.